# Python Tkinter GUI File Menu Not Displaying though GUI is operational

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm sure this is an error with the structure of my code, but I cannot seem to get the filemenu to display in my GUI. Can someone tell me what errors I have made with the filemenu inclusion? Also, I am sorry, but the spacing after copying and pasting is a little off. The class indentation level is proper on my side. I am using Python 3.71

Any other comments on better or more Pythonic ways to accomplish what I have here are also welcome and thank you for your help in advance!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
import os
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class UserGui(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent=parent
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.parent.configure(bg='white')
        self.frame1_style = ttk.Style()
        self.frame1_style.configure('My.TFrame', background='white')
        self.frame2_style = ttk.Style()
        self.frame2_style.configure('My2.TFrame',background='white')
        self.parent.title("TGUI")


        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.parent, style='My.TFrame') #Creating Total Window Frame 1
        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

        self.frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.parent, width=100, height=20, style='My2.TFrame')
        self.frame2.grid(row=0, column=6, padx=20, pady=5)


        #Menu Creation
        self.menu1 = tk.Menu(self.parent, tearoff=0)
        self.parent.config(menu=self.menu1)
        self.fileMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu1, tearoff=0)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.donothing)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.donothing)

        self.fileMenu.add_separator()

        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.parent.quit)
        self.fileMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.menu1)

        self.editMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu1, tearoff=0)
        self.editMenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=self.donothing)
        self.editMenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=self.donothing)
        self.editMenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=self.donothing)
        self.editMenu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=self.menu1)    

    def donothing(self):
        filewin = Toplevel(self.parent)
        button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
        button.pack()



def main():
    root=tk.Tk()
    ug=UserGui(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit 1,2,3: I have corrected the `add_cascade` option for `menu` with `menu=self.menu1` and I still do not have a file menu displaying.

Comment: You are adding your File and Edit menus to *themselves*, rather than the top-level menu.

Comment: You need to fix the indentation problems in your example code.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for your comment. Even when I switched the menu option pointer to `menu=self.menu1` in the add_cascade lines for the fileMenu and editMenu, I still did not get the menu bar with "File" and "Edit" to populate.

Comment: That made it worse, actually.  Try `self.menu1.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fileMenu)`

Comment: @JasonHarper , that solved it. Thank you very much for your comment. That call makes way more sense. I had my dependencies completely flipped in my understanding. If you want to copy & paste that to an answer I will mark it as such so others can reference this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post this answer for completeness considering @JasonHarper has not copied it to an answer format and I want others to be able to benefit from the post.

The key was the object that I was calling the `add_cascade` on the child `Menu` widget object instead of the main `Menu` widget object called `self.menu1`. The key was changing:

`self.fileMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.menu1)`

to :

```
self.menu1.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fileMenu)
```

This was the proper way of adding the `fileMenu` `Menu` object to the total `Menu` widget object of `self.menu1`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I'm sorry I didn't notice the Python-3 tag in time, it's all the same except when inherriting you would call `super().__init__` instead of the `Frame.__init__` directly. That would make it more Py3-like. Even so, this should still work.

Weirdly, pushing the menu.config down to the `run` function worked for me - even though it looks like it should work the way you did it.

```
def main():
    root=tk.Tk()
    ug=UserGui(root)
    root.config(menu=ug.fileMenu)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Oterwise there are some things you can work on to make it more OOP like and readable. THis is how I usually handle making GUIs. The idea is to split the GUI's into `Frames` that then do simmilar things. I.e. your app could have left and right Frame where the RightFrame would hold the textbox ad the left Frame would actually have 2 sub frames - one for the names and dropdowns and the other for the buttons. That way each individual functionality is handled by the Frames themselves and it's not all in one giant class, the elements in those Frames are placed relative to the Frame's grid itself, while all the Frames are placed in the MainFrame's grid. This lets you split a lot of code into modules as well and helps with maintainability.

The sub-frames emit "global" events (events bothering other frames) by propagating them through the MainFrame, that's why they all carry a self.parent - their parent frame, and a self.root - the MainFrame. The MainFrame is also the Frame in which I like to put something like `self.data` which itself is a class on its own (outside Tkinter) that handles all the data input/output and logic so that you don't clutter the GUI code logic with data calculations and logic. Ideally the Data class would handle data errors and GUI would only then have to handle any errors in logic (such as selecting two impossible-to-combine options from the dropdown menus.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class SubFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, text="Top Right"):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack()  
        self.parent = parent
        self.root = parent.root
        self.label=Label(self, text=text).pack()


class RightFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        self.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.root = parent
        self.label = Label(self, text="Right Frame").pack()


class LeftFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        self.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.root = parent
        self.label = Label(self, text="Left Frame").pack()

        #again Frames which would have a parent class RightFrame and root MainFrame
        self.subFrame1 = SubFrame(self)
        self.subFrame2 = SubFrame(self, text="Top Right SubFrame 2") 

class MainFrame(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("1100x600")
        self.title("Working Example")

        self.leftFrame = LeftFrame(self)
        self.rightFrame = RightFrame(self)
        #self.data = MagicalDataHandlingClass()



def run():
    app = MainFrame()
    app.mainloop()
```

**EDIT** answer to comments that are too long to fit

The call to `Frame.__init__(...)` is made because the class definition looks like `class LeftFrame(Frame)`. Usually to declare a class what you would write is just `class LeftFrame`. When you add the bit in the `()` what is happening is called inheritance. When you inherit from a class (called parent), your class (called child) inherits all of the methods and attributes of parent. But much like you have to initialize your class to get an object, i.e. `lf = LeftFrame(...)` the parent class has to be initialized too. In Python this initialization is done by calling the special dunder `__init__(...)` function. So that call to `Frame.__init__(...)` happens because you need to tell the parent class what are all the values it needs to work properly. In Python 3 however it is recommended that instead of instantiating the parent by name like that you use the `super` function like `super().__init__(....)`. This happens for a lot of complicated reasons most of which you probably don't have to worry about for a while yet (such as what if you inherit from multiple classes at the same time, what if you inherit from a class that inherited from a different one, etc...). I wouldn't try to feel overwhelmed by understanding the complete power of `super()` if you're just starting because 99% of the time in Python 3 just doing `super().__init__(...)` will do exactly what you want even if you don't understand. If you feel like getting in over your head [Raymond Hettinger](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) has a good writeup of Super is Super and why exactly it's so much better than old way.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I will definitely make the appropriate edits for this structure as I was just running into the same line of thought myself. The answer to my original problem on the file menu was in the comments for the post, but this is highly appreciated. I tried to run your code "as-is" and I am new to Python so the super() is not familiar to me. I have tried reading it in [link](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function), but I do not fully understand.

Comment: @whisperquiet answered the question as an edit because it's too long for comments. Yes, you should definitely accept Jason's answer if/when he posts it, upvotes are appreciated though but karma-sellout in me hates saying it, so do what you think is right.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of super and the concept of inheritance, your help is extremely appreciated. Just to clarify, to get a Python 3+ running version of the code you've posted, I would change the following:

`Frame.__init__(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)` to `super().__init__(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)` 

And then apply the change structure to the LeftFrame and MainFrame class definitions? 

I have tried implementing this because what you say makes sense, but it is still not functioning. In your `run()` definition do I have to include anything else?

Comment: I would most certainly upvote, but I just created this account and do not have enough reputation to upvote!

Comment: @whisperquiet THe code I posted originally was just a sketch of an idea. There's a bunch of stuff missing, it's more like "here's the ouline of a design". I've updated the code to something that works on my system. It should work by just calling `run` on yours too. You have to play around with the pack or grid now to get all the frames where you want them exactly and then fill them in with functionality you need.

Comment: Ah! I am sorry for my misunderstanding and thank you very much for your repeated attention to this post, it helps more than I can express in words! For some reason with my current setup, when I changed: `def run():` to `def main():` and subsequently added the 

`if __name__ == '__main__': main()` 

Then this new updated code ran on my system. 

Thank you for the lesson and when I get a high enough reputation I will drop back to upvote!

Comment: @whisperquiet: Forget about it, not a big deal. I misled you though. It's been a while sine I used `ttk` and it seems that `super()` won't work because `ttk` still has not caught up with the new style classes used in Python 3 by default. So you're stick using the old way. Sorry, I just read about it.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, but I have one last question regarding the SubFrame class that you've built. Why is the SubFrame call under LeftFrame associating it with the RightFrame? I would assume that SubFrame called with `self` would be associated with LeftFrame in your code. I am not understanding the SubFrame `__init__` definition.

Comment: I didn't use `ttk` for a while and forgot some details. Their geometry managers (`pack` or `grid`) are not intuitive and take a lot of fiddling to get them right. So instead of renaming the classes I just copied the subframes into the one that got me the correct result for the text. The two places where you can put things is either in their init or in their parent. Writing `self.pack()` in `SubFrame` should be equivalent to removing it from there and adding `self.subframe1.pack()` in `LeftFrame` (same for `self.leftframe.pack()` in `MainFrame`). It's just a matter of choice and consistency.